# check if user opens a file in python

Tags: python, filesystems, python-os

I am trying to make a simple script where if you open a declared file (test.exe/text.txt), it would print "you opened *text.txt*" or "you have opened *test.exe*". Is there any simple way to do this in Python?

Answer (score 0):

Install 'psutil' library:
On Linux:

```
pip3 install psutil
```

On Windows:

```
pip install psutil
```

Module **psutil** has function **psutil.process_iter()** which gives a list of process names which are working on your computer, after you can check if your typed application work or not. If you want more information about the library please check the official documentation and how to use it.

```
# import module
import psutil
  
# check if application is open
application_name = "application.something"
output = application_name in (i.name() for i in psutil.process_iter())
if output is True:
    print(f"you have opened {application_name}"
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working. Import "psutil" could not be resolved from source. I installed it so I don't see what the problem would be

Comment: @aram-simonyan your answer depends on an external library, provide more information about it.

Comment: @cristianoms: That's really good feedback and would definitely improve the answer. Since it's a well-known library that the contributor isn't responsible for, however, that's not a sufficient reason to recommend deletion of the answer.